# Plaid - can't run (python) quickstart

Tags: javascript, python, html, plaid

I'm working with the Plaid API [found here](https://github.com/plaid/quickstart/tree/master/python) but can't seem to get the quickstart to run properly. My latest attempt is below

```
import base64
import os
...
...
app = Flask(__name__)

# Fill in your Plaid API keys - https://dashboard.plaid.com/account/keys
PLAID_CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxx' #os.getenv('xxxxx')
PLAID_SECRET = 'xxxxx' #os.getenv('xxxx')
...
PLAID_ENV = 'sandbox' #os.getenv('PLAID_ENV', 'sandbox')
...
PLAID_PRODUCTS = 'transactions' #os.getenv('PLAID_PRODUCTS', 'transactions').split(',')
...
PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES = 'US' #os.getenv('PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES', 'US').split(',')


def empty_to_none(field):
  value = os.getenv(field)
  if value is None or len(value) == 0:
    return None
  return field
...
PLAID_REDIRECT_URI = empty_to_none('http://localhost:8000/oauth-response.html')

client = plaid.Client(client_id=PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
                  secret=PLAID_SECRET,
                  environment=PLAID_ENV,
                  api_version='2019-05-29')

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html',)
```

When I run server.py and open the browser the button can't be selected. Also the list of banks just continuously loads. So I check chrome dev tools I find the error `link-initialize.js:1 Uncaught Error: Missing Link parameter. Link requires a key or token to be provided.` Is this because I didn't pass something in render_template? I can't tell from the index.html file [found here](https://github.com/plaid/quickstart/blob/master/html/index.html) & currently that's the only front end document referenced in the (python) repository. I looked at the question [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266699/plaid-api-quickstart-project-error-http-127-0-0-15000-get-access-token) but it's several years old & I believe the integration has changed...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're specifying a REDIRECT_URI but haven't configured the developer dashboard to accept that as your URI.

Unfortunately, the error messaging is currently swallowed and only visible in the network tab.  We're going to fix it so that these errors are propagated into a place where they're more visible.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for reply. I pulled latest update of index.html & the errors were right there on the page. I also configured the REDIRECT_URI so it appears OK for now. The button can be selected & I get a list of banks. I'll continue to work my way through it & reach back out if I have additional issues.